# Place Order Doesnt work

Tags: shopping-cart, shopping

I run multiple sites and i notice on both magento sites i have had recurring problems or customers getting all the way through filling out their billing info and getting to the last step of "place your order" and it just simply doesnt work. If there is any insight on this problem please let me know thanks!